# Logshipping is failing intermitently

Tags: sql-server-2012

Client has setup logshipping one of the database. Out of 3 steps in logshipping - backup and copy works without any issues, but restore fails intermittently giving 'out of sync' error.

When I pulled backup/restore history using query, I am getting some entry with 'NUL' for physical device name as shown below.
[image]

Is that is causing issue? How to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your log shipping is working fine. Just remove additional log backups from maintenance plans since they can break log shipping.

Comment: Yep.  Track down the job taking a log backup to disk=‘nul’ and disable it.  Then ensure that any other full recovery databases have scheduled log backups.

Comment: I am not finding any additional log backup from any of the maintenance plan & also I an not finding any job taking a log backup to disk=‘nul’. Is there any system level events trigger this?

Comment: The link given below suggests  to disable 'SQL Server VSS Writer' to resolve the issue. Now I have disabled this service both in Primary and Secondary servers. Let us see how it goes. Link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b229277-7619-4c98-a2ee-a0a65ae66d5d/backup-entries-from-unknown-source-sql-server-2008-windows-server-2008?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Issue got resolved by disabling service 'SQL Server VSS Writer'

Comment: If the SQL Writer service is disabled, any utility which in relies on VSS snapshots, such as System Center Data Protection Manager, as well as some other 3rd-party products, would be broken, or worse, at risk of taking backups of databases which were not consistent. Test it setting to start manually instead.